# How can I repeat a value into a range using a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to do something like this:

[image]

The value can be a character or some words.

If the value is number (for example = 0) then I can do:

```
sequence(11,6,0,0)
```

But I can't use a character or words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SEQUENCE(11,6,0,0), "0", "A"))`

This uses `SEQUENCE` but substitutes the "0" values for the required text value.